# Vertically Centered Background Image on Scrolling TextBox

Tags: wpf, windows

We are using a TextBox in a Windows application to show console output from a server application. It it scrolling so that older output can be read.

The aim is to have a background image that is always at the same position, in the centre of the TextView, regardless of the scroll position or amount of content.

There is already a background image set, which is set to centre for X and Y position, but this means that you must be scrolled to exactly in the centre of the view where the text is held to see it.

I also tried aligning the Y axis to the bottom and using an offset, but this meant that the background image was not visible when scrolling from the bottom position.

An example of what we want to achieve can be seen on the Appium.app project.

[image: Appium.app]

Comment: You will have to put your `Image` and the `ScrollViewer` inside a grid, one on top of another and the scroll wouldn't affect your image.

Comment: Also, I'm new to asking questions on StackOverflow. Why did I get down-voted?

Comment: The absence of a code example, i would bet...